# Editing the sudo file in a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed

I want to edit the sudoers files in Solaris by removing `#` or adding `#` in it on a specific line, so how can I write the script for this? My sudoer sample file given below:

```
# The following line allows su without options/arguments and sux to user root
Cmnd_Alias SU_ROOT = /usr/bin/su "",\
                     /usr/local/bin/sux - root

# Defaults specification
Defaults:%saptb !authenticate

# User privilege specification
%saptb  ALL=(root)SU_SAP
#Uncomment this line when SAP requires root access
%saptb ALL=(root)SU_ROOT
##### END SAP-TB specific  ######
#
#
#Tivoli ITM Tools Team Sudo Right
#
%cgtools        ALL=(root)       NOPASSWD: /opt/IBM/ITM/bin/*
```

---

In this above sudoers file i want add `#` before the only line of `%saptb ALL=(root)SU_ROOT`

Answer (score 2):

Do a substitution with `sed`:

```
# Comment out the line %saptb ALL=(root)SU_ROOT
sudo sed -Ei 's/^(%saptb.*SU_ROOT.*)/#\1/' /etc/sudoers
```

Explanation:

`-E` use extended `regex`

`-i` edit the file in place.

```
s/         # Substitution
^          # Match the start of the line
(          # Capture the following
%saptb     # Followed by %saptb
.*         # Followed by anything
SU_ROOT    # Followed by SU_ROOT
.*         # Followed by anything
)          # Close capture
/          # Replace with 
#          # A hash 
\1         # Followed by the captured line
```

To uncomment lines the principle is the same:

1. Match the start of the line
2. Followed by a `#`
3. Capture the rest of the line
4. Replace whole line with captured part of the line (throwing away the `#`).

So:

```
# Uncomment the line %saptb ALL=(root)SU_ROOT
sudo sed -Ei 's/^#(%saptb.*SU_ROOT.*)/\1/' /etc/sudoers
```

---

You can use the following script to comment/uncomment by running `sudo ./toggle.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

# Is the line already commented out
grep -q '#%saptb ALL=(root)SU_ROOT' /etc/sudoers

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then 
    # Uncomment the line %saptb ALL=(root)SU_ROOT
    sed -Ei 's/^#(%saptb.*SU_ROOT.*)/\1/' /etc/sudoers
else 
    # Comment out the line %saptb ALL=(root)SU_ROOT
    sed -Ei 's/^(%saptb.*SU_ROOT.*)/#\1/' /etc/sudoers
fi
```